# Firebird и компонент "TIBRestoreService"

Tags: delphi, firebird, компоненты, interbase

У меня стоит "*Delphi 10.2*", и я решил воспольльзоваться компонентом «*TIBRestoreService*», для восстановления БД на «*Firebird 2.5*».
Проблема в том, что на строке «*ServiceStart*;»

```
          with IBRestoreService do
          begin
            Attach;
            try
              LNameDB := StringReplace(ExtractFileName(ExtractFileName(edPathDB.Text)), ExtractFileExt(ExtractFileName(edPathDB.Text)),'',[]);
             BackupFile.Clear;
             BackupFile.Add('d:\Export_Import\Plan.gbk');
             DatabaseName.Add('d:\Export_Import\PLAN.GDB');

              ServiceStart;
              While not Eof do
              begin
                Application.ProcessMessages;
                mReportRestore.Lines.Add(GetNextLine);
              end;
              finally
              begin
                Detach;
              end;
            end;
```

Вылазит ошибка:

> ..exception class Exception with message 'Service API write mode is an
>   InterBase XE3 function. Please upgrade to InterBase XE3 to use this
>   functonality'

причем при все этом, если нажать "*continue*", БД всетаки восстанавливается.

также у меня и установлен на ПК "...\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\InterBaseXE7..."

Я бы поставил «InterBase», но проблема в том, что он будет конфликтовать с «Firebird».
Да еще при установке «Interbase 12.0.5.372 (x64)», система пишет:

> The description for Event ID 0 from source IBS_gds_db cannot be found.
>   Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your
>   local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or
>   repair the component on the local computer. If the event originated on
>   another computer, the display information had to be saved with the
>   event. The following information was included with the event: 
>   IBS_gds_db error: 1063 StartServiceCtrlDispatcher failed

и "ibserver.exe" конечно не ставится

2 вопроса:
1 Мне действительно нужно ставить «Interbase 12.0.5.372 (x64)»? или есть другой выход?
2 У меня система х64, но приложение будет работать под х32. Interbase можно поставить х64. (проблем с запуском на х32 не будет)?

Answer (score 0):

Interbase ставить не нужно. Похоже, что твоё приложение использует не ту клиентскую библиотеку (gds32.dll) - от Interbase, а надо от Firebird.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, речь идёт о свойстве [WriteMode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/IBX.IBServices.TIBRestoreService.WriteMode) компонента TIBRestoreService. Оно документировано в обычном для Embarcadero стиле: "Embarcadero Technologies does not currently have any additional information". :)  В [руководстве](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/interbase/IB2017Update2/DevGuide.pdf) разработчика по Interbase 2017 есть описание этого свойства:

> InterBase allows you to write to databases in both synchronous and
>   asynchronous modes. In synchronous mode, the database writes are
>   forced. In asynchronous mode, the database writes are buffered.

При использовании Firebird вместо Interbase вы видите Exception, который не влияет на работу и не доходит до пользователя.