# У меня проблемы с «gds32.dll», Firebird3 и Delphi10.2

Tags: windows, delphi, dll, библиотеки

У меня программа (БД) (написана *Delphi7*) работает под *Firebird*. Также на ПК также стоит и *Delphi10.2* (со своим *Client InterBase*).
Программа использует компонент «*IBBackupService1*», который использует «*GetNextLine method*».
С некоторого времени на этом методе стала возникать ошибка:

> «…. exception class EIBInterBaseError with message 'unavailable
>   database unknown ISC error 336330835'

Я вычитал, что это из-за неправильного подхвата программой «*gds32.dll*». 
Правда у меня на ПК стоит аж **4** библиотеки «*gds32.dll*» и разного размера, см. рис.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да и я на этом ПК, то инсталлировал, то деинсталлировал *FB*. (и у меня в *system32* стоят «*gds32.dll*» только от *FB*)

На другом ПК, на котором стоит только *FB* и одна «*gds32.dll*» (и я удалил все лишние «*gds32.dll*», когда-то там тоже стоял *InterBase*), таких проблем нет.
Мне, что нужно теперь в *Delphi10.2*, сносить «*Client InterBase*»?

Да, я еще для Delphi7 ставил обновления "IBXDP705.EXE" и "IBXDP708.EXE" - но это было давно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Описанная вами ситуация носит название [DLL Hell](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_hell). Чтобы ее избежать **никогда** не копируйте файлы в System32.

Используйте либо полный путь к dll при ее загрузке или положите правильную версию dll в папку с exe-файлом.

Comment: что-то не очень помогает, копирование "gds32.dll" в дирректорию с программой. Ошибка остается. Я нахожусь на 64 разрядной системе и пробовал поочередно копировать обе версии dll, точнее версия одна, но разный размер. На том ПК, на котором программа работает установлена 32-х разрядная ОС

Comment: Возьмите файл `fbclient.dll` из папки `Firebird\bin\` и скопируйте его в каталог программы, изменив его имя на `gds32.dll`

Comment: Значит либо вы запускаете другой файл, либо exe загружает библиотеку с другим именем, либо библиотека загружается с указанием полного пути. Сам exe, случайно, удалить нельзя? Запускаете ProcessMonitor и смотрите, что ищется и где.

Comment: Да,да, я уже переменовал файлы gds32.dll в system32 и SysWow64, перезапустил сервер, теперь при запуске программы, ошибку "Exception EIBClientError in module setting.dll at 0008DDB4." кидает одна из моих библиотек   . Exe - запускаю с Totalcommander

Comment: Хотя может это и не библиотека, я сравнил их с ПК "WinXP" (х32) system32 и Win 10 (x64) SysWOW64, они одинаковы, тем более 2 недели назад я на ПК Win10 компилировал этот же код - было все норм. Меня просто запутала https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/800892/firebird-и-компонент-tibrestoreservice

Comment: когда БД/сервер стоит на Win10, там где и клиент - коннект норм.
как, только я коннекчусь на виртуалку (с WinXP)  "192.168.0.110:D:\Database\examp.FDB" - сразу лезет ошибка, а потом данные на клиенте всеравно появляются.
Точно также, если я на виртуалке (c WinXp) запущу клиента и законнекчусь на локальный сервер - все норм.Т.е. дело в сети получается.

Comment: т.е. "*GetNextLine method*", кидает ошибку, когда я коннекчусь на удаленнвй сервер "*192.168.0.110:D:\Database\examp.FDB*"

Comment: Если дело не в библиотеке, то отметьте мой вопрос как верный, а сами задайте новый вопрос

Answer (score 0):

1) Удалить все gds32.dll, скопировать в System32 правильную от Firebird. Если вы не используете коннекты к Interbase (именно Interbase) из программ на Дельфи xe10, то прокатит.

2) Если в Дельфи 7 коннект через FIBPlus, то в файле проекта пишете

```
uses 
  .. ibase...
...
begin
  IBASE_DLL = 'mycollfbclient.dll'; //любое имя
```

...
и переименовываете gds32.dll от Firebird в mycollfbclient.dll. Достаточно кинуть ее в каталог с программой или можно в System32.
Правда в разных версиях FIBPlus это может быть константой, а может переменной.

3) Если в Дельфи 7 используете IBX, то смотрите файл IBHeader.pas на предмет IBASE_DLL. В моем Дельфи 6 это константа. Значит либо исправляете ее на var, либо название на другое прямо в IBHeader.pas и перекомпилируете, если получится.

Сообщите

- какая у вас версия Firebird
- есть ли исходники программы на Дельфи 7
- какие компоненты доступа вы в ней используете

Answer (score 0):

Самое надёжное решение DLL hell (см. пост от Anton Shchyrov) - привязать Firebird к вашему приложению с помощью manifest. Подкладывание dll в свой каталог не всегда приводит к необходимому эффекту, несмотря на то, что порядок загрузки DLL документирован.

Вкратце, сборка Firebird должна находиться в отдельном каталоге (рядом с exe-файлом приложения), и там же содержится файл с её описанием (название файла эквивалентно названию каталога, с расширением .manifest):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <noInheritable/>
    <assemblyIdentity 
        type="win32" 
        name="Firebird.25" 
        version="2.5.8.27089" 
        processorArchitecture="x86" 
    />
    <file name="gds32.dll"/>
    <file name="ib_util.dll"/>
    <file name="icudt30.dll"/>
    <file name="icuin30.dll"/>
    <file name="icuuc30.dll"/>
</assembly>
```

Далее, для приложения готовится свой manifest-файл, содержащий указание на сборку (хранить можно где угодно - этот файл будет включен в exe-файл как ресурс):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1' manifestVersion='1.0'>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Firebird.25' version='2.5.8.27089' processorArchitecture='x86' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Manifest-файл приложения нужно указать в настройках проекта, раздел "Application -> Manifest". Теперь при попытке приложения загрузить библиотеку gds23.dll она всегда будет получена из локальной сборки. В случае отсутствия сборки рядом с exe-файлом приложение не будет запускаться.